# Converting Ruby hashes to arrays

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Hash which is of the form 
`{:a => {"aa" => 11,"ab" => 12}, :b => {"ba" => 21,"bb" => 22}}`

How do i convert it to the form `{:a => [["aa",11],["ab",12]],:b=>[["ba",21],["bb",22]]}`

Comment: If you're working with multi-level hashes and you want to flatten them check out my HashModel gem: https://rubygems.org/gems/hashmodel and you can get the source on github: https://github.com/mikbe/hashmodel

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you want to modify the original hash you can do:

```
hash.each_pair { |key, value| hash[key] = value.to_a }
```

From the documentation for [Hash#to_a](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Hash.html#method-i-to_a)

> Converts hsh to a nested array of [
>   key, value ] arrays.
>
> `h = { "c" => 300, "a" => 100, "d" => 400, "c" => 300  }`
>
> `h.to_a #=> [["c", 300], ["a", 100], ["d", 400]]`

Comment: Thank you @mikej. Worked like a charm, though I'd like to know what the difference between hash.each and hash.each_pair is ?

Comment: If you don't want to modify the original hash, you can use this: `new_hash = hash.inject({}) { |h, (key, value)| h[key] = value.to_a; h }`

Comment: @Aditya: If you want your block to get two parameters, use `each_pair`. If only for readability.

Answer (score 4):

Here is another way to do this :

```
hsh = {:a => {"aa" => 11,"ab" => 12}, :b => {"ba" => 21,"bb" => 22}}
hsh.each{|k,v| hsh[k]=*v}
# => {:a=>[["aa", 11], ["ab", 12]], :b=>[["ba", 21], ["bb", 22]]}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
hash.collect {|a, b|  [a, hash[a].collect {|c,d| [c,d]}] }.collect {|e,f| [e => f]}
```