# How to save an array of information coming from a hash in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I am new to ruby and don't have much experience with hashes, I have a variable named tweets and it is a hash as such:

```
{"statuses"=>[{"metadata"=>{"result_type"=>"recent", "iso_language_code"=>"tl"}, "lang"=>"tl"}]}
```

I would like to save the array of information as a separate variable in an array. How would I go about this?

Comment: What that array should look like?

Comment: is should look like:
[{"metadata"=>{"result_type"=>"recent", "iso_language_code"=>"tl"}, "lang"=>"tl"}]

Comment: I think you should consider flattening the whole into a another ..that will be simpler than a array..

Comment: How would this be done?

Comment: You mean like: `new_array = tweets['statuses'].dup`? (The `dup` to make sure `new_array` doesn't get altered by changes to `tweets`)

Comment: new_array = tweets['statuses'].dup worked great. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a Hash like so:

```
hash = {:numbers => [1,2,3,4]}
```

And you need to capture the array into a new variable. You can just access the key and assign it to a new variable like so:

```
one_to_five = hash[:numbers]
```

However, note that the new variable actually holds the array that is in the hash. So altering the hash's array alters the new variable's array.

```
hash[:numbers] << 6
puts one_to_five #=> [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

If you use `dup`, it will create a copy of the array so it will be two separate arrays.

```
one_to_five = hash[:numbers].dup
hash[:numbers] << 6
puts one_to_five #=> [1,2,3,4,5]
```

So, in your case:

```
hash = {'statuses' => [{"metadata"=>{"result_type"=>"recent", "iso_language_code"=>"tl"}, "lang"=>"tl"}]}
new_array = hash['statuses'].dup
```

However, it would be interesting to see what it is you are wishing to accomplish with your code, or at least get a little more context, because this may not be the best approach for your final goal. There are a great many things you can do with [Arrays](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html) and [Hashes](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Hash.html) (and [Enumerable](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html)) and I would encourage you to read through the documentation on them.

Answer (score 1):

Hash's have 2 very nice methods,

```
hash.values
hash.keys
```

in your case -

```
h = {"statuses"=>[{"metadata"=>{"result_type"=>"recent", "iso_language_code"=>"tl"}, "lang"=>"tl"}]}
p h.values
p.keys
```

These output arrays of each type. This might be what you want.

Also, this question will very well be closed. 1 Google search reported several Hash to Array SO questions.

[Ruby Hash to array of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9560335/ruby-hash-to-array-of-values)
[Converting Ruby hashes to arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4591949/converting-ruby-hashes-to-arrays)

Comment: hash.values doesnt work because it creates a new array of the array. I cant have the extra array